# Adverse Events Reported Term + MEDDRA coding dataset

Tags: data-request, openfda, medical

I just wanted to kindly ask if anyone is aware of the presence of a repository of datasets containing both the Reported Term (usually collected in the CRF as free text by the investigator) and its relative MedDRA coding.

I tried to check the FAERS databases, they could have been my perfect solution, but they don't include the Reported Term, only the coded term from the MedDRA dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one the many folks working on Open FDA. We've searched across FDA data sets open to the public and, unfortunately, did not identify one that would  meet your requirement at this time.